# Horizontal alignment of an augmented matrix

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

Is there a way to align the vertical line in an augmented matrix (to have them underneath in an aligned equation)? When the signs in the matrix change, it becomes distorted and I am looking for a better visual representation for that case.

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
    \rightsquigarrow
    &\left( \begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
       2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
       2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{array}\right)
    \rightsquigarrow\\
    \text{II} - \text{I}, \text{III}-\text{I}\rightsquigarrow
    &\left( \begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
       2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       0 & -3 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
       0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{array}\right)
    \rightsquigarrow
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceMatrixBlock}` with a key `auto-columns-width`. In that environment, all the columns of all the environments of `nicematrix` (`{NiceMatrix}`, `{NiceArray}`, `{NiceTabular}`, etc.) will have the same width. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]

\begin{align*}
    \rightsquigarrow
    &\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}
       2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
       2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{pNiceArray}
    \rightsquigarrow\\
    \text{II} - \text{I}, \text{III}-\text{I}\rightsquigarrow
    &\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}
       2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       0 & -3 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
       0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{pNiceArray}
    \rightsquigarrow
\end{align*}

\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you a lot, that really helps. Am I correct that there is a larger space between the penultimate and ultimate column compared to the others?

Comment: You are right. I have modified my answer. With the environment `{pNiceArray}`, the result  is better and there is not this artefact.

Answer (score 2):

I propose two ways depending on whether you want columns to be aligned too:

First way:

[image]

Second way:

[image]

Code for the first output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  & \rightsquigarrow
  & \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
             2 & 4 & 3 \\
             2 & 1 & 2 \\
             2 & 4 & 2 \\
  \end{array} \right|
  &
    \left. \begin{array}{@{}rrr}
             1 & 0 & 0 \\
             0 & 1 & 0 \\
             0 & 0 & 2 \\
           \end{array} \right)
  && \rightsquigarrow\\
  \text{II} - \text{I}, \text{III}-\text{I}
  & \rightsquigarrow
  & \;                          % add a little space after the arrow
    \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
             2 &  4 &  3 \\
             0 & -3 & -1 \\
             0 &  0 & -1 \\
           \end{array}\right|
  &
    \left. \begin{array}{@{}rrr}
              1 & 0 & 0 \\
             -1 & 1 & 0 \\
             -1 & 0 & 2 \\
           \end{array} \right)
  &&\rightsquigarrow
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Code for the second output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Let's have fun and spare one skip register.
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@@mydefineColType}[2]{%
  \newcolumntype{#2}{>{$}W{r}{#1}<{$}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@mydefineColType}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@mydefineColType\expandafter{\the#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\mydefineColType}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@mydefineColType\my@exchange{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\my@exchange}[2]{{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}%
\settowidth{\mylength}{$-3$}%
% For columns containing at least one negative number
\mydefineColType{N}{\mylength}% stores the current value of \mylength
\settowidth{\mylength}{$3$}%
% For columns containing no negative number
\mydefineColType{P}{\mylength}% stores the current value of \mylength

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  & \rightsquigarrow \; % add a little space after the arrow
  & \left( \begin{array}{PNN}
             2 & 4 & 3 \\
             2 & 1 & 2 \\
             2 & 4 & 2 \\
  \end{array} \right|
  &
    \left. \begin{array}{@{}NPP}
             1 & 0 & 0 \\
             0 & 1 & 0 \\
             0 & 0 & 2 \\
           \end{array} \right)
  && \rightsquigarrow\\
  \text{II} - \text{I}, \text{III}-\text{I}
  & \rightsquigarrow \; % add a little space after the arrow
  & \left( \begin{array}{PNN}
             2 &  4 &  3 \\
             0 & -3 & -1 \\
             0 &  0 & -1 \\
           \end{array}\right|
  &
    \left. \begin{array}{@{}NPP}
              1 & 0 & 0 \\
             -1 & 1 & 0 \\
             -1 & 0 & 2 \\
           \end{array} \right)
  &&\rightsquigarrow
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility with the `\MoveEqLeft` command from `mathtools`. Tha value of the optional argument was found by trial & error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \rightsquigarrow
   \MoveEqLeft[-1.55]\left( \begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
       2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
       2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{array}\right)
    \rightsquigarrow\\
    \text{II} - \text{I}, \text{III}-\text{I}\rightsquigarrow
    &\left( \begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
       2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       0 & -3 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
       0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{array}\right)
    \rightsquigarrow
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]